# Very strange harddisc behaviour

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, sata, docking-station, md5

Running Windows 7 64bit.

Harddisc is installed internally and connected via SATA: Videofile xyz.mp4 can be opened and played without any problems.

If I remove the disc and put it in an external dockingstation (connected to the computer via USB) the videofile xyz.mp4 seems to be broken. Can't be opened or played. MD5 value of the very same file is different from when the disc was connected directly to the motherboard via SATA.

If I put the disc back in and connect it via SATA again I can read the file without any problems. If I put the disc in the docking station again the file seems to be broken again. And so on. The issue can be reproduced every time. The problem exists just for a few files on the entire harddisc. All other files work fine with both connection methods. I already tried to run checkdisk in "repair broken sectors" mode but it didn't find anything.

This behaviour totally beats my understanding of computers and logic. What am I missing here?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the docking station.

Comment: The external USB HDD docking station have completely different controller, meaning that it is possible that you have compatibility issue between your HDD and external controller. What is the size of the MP4 file?     Edit: it is also possible that USB enclosure have some problem like @Ramhound mentioned above

Comment: Size of the mp4 file is roughly 1GB.
If there is a compatibility issue between the internal and external controller: wouldn't it be more probable that in such a case ALL files were affected instead of just a few ones?

Comment: @user270288 - Video files depending on the codec are very prone to corruption.  Other type of data might not be.  Have you tried a different docking station?